# Laravel: After upgrade JWT then session expire become too often

Tags: php, laravel, apache, authentication, jwt

so, i upgrade my `jwt` package on my **Laravel v5.8**, I need to upgrade because of security issue. However, upgrading `jwt` is not easy, too many trial & error. Finally, i found a solution from it's [github repository here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1678) then `jwt` upgrade is **finish**.

==========

The summary of solution by adding:

(1) Upgrade **jwt** by `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.* --prefer-source`

(2) Change below line in `config/app.php`, before:

```
'providers' => [
...
'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' ,
...
]
```

**into**

```
'providers' => [
...
'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' ,
...
]
```

(3) Add `implements JWTSubject` into `User` Model Class

(4) Add below line into `User` Model Class:

```
public function getJWTIdentifier()
{
   return $this->getKey();
}

public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
   return [];
}
```

(5) run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"`

==========

However, **it has side effect**.

Now, every login sessions do not last long.

Before this fix, it sometimes need a month for a login session to expire, **but now it just need a couple of hour**. Moreover, no other logic/coding added except above.

Any Idea/Solution?

Thank You in Advance...

Comment: You've not given us much info related to that actual problem (ie debugging results, the config for the jwt package, or even how long "every login sessions do not last long." is exactly. Are we talking an hour, 5 minutes, on next page load? That said, I would start by checking if the current version of the repo requires some settings file that is either missing, has missing values in it, or has been renamed from your very old version.

Answer (score 2):

Time to live is defined in the `config/jwt.php`.

See the line that says `'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60)` which means by default the token will be valid for 1 hour.

If you don't already have that, be sure to run the following command to publish the package config file:

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I will try